# Plotting mesh data from vtk python using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mesh, vtk

*The following questions makes use of vtk python but what I am attempting to do should not require any knowledge of vtk because I have converted the data I wish to plot into numpy arrays described below. If anyone does know of an improvement to the way I go about actually processing the vtk data into numpy, please let me know!*

I have some data that I have extracted using vtk python. The data consists of a 3D unstructured grid and has several 'blocks'. The block I am interested in is `block0`. The data is contained at each cell rather than at each point. I wish to plot a contourf plot of a scalar variable on this grid using matplotlib. In essence my problem comes down to the following:

Given a set of cell faces with known vertices in space and a known scalar field variable, create a contour plot as one would get if one had created a `numpy.meshgrid` and used `plt.contourf/plt.pcolormesh` etc. Basically I post process my vtk data like so:

```
numCells = block0.GetCells().GetNumberOfCells()

# Array of the 8 vertices that make up a cell in 3D
cellPtsArray = np.zeros((numCells,8,3)) 

# Array of the 4 vertices that make up a cell face
facePtsArray = np.zeros((numCells,4,3)) 

#Array to store scalar field value from each cell
valueArray = np.zeros((numCells,1)) 

for i in xrange(numCells):
    cell = block0.GetCell(i)
    numCellPts = cell.GetNumberOfPoints() 

    for j in xrange(numCellPts):
        cellPtsArray[i,j,:] = block0.GetPoint(cell.GetPointId(j)) 

    valueArray[i] = block0.GetCellData().GetArray(3).GetValue(i)
    xyFacePts = cell.GetFaceArray(3) 
    facePtsArray[i,:,:] = cellPtsArray[i,xyFacePts,:]
```

Now I wish to create a contour plot of this data (fill each cell in space according to an appropriate colormap of the scalar field variable). Is there a good built in function in matplotlib to do this? **Note that I cannot use any form of automatic triangulation-the connectivity of the mesh is already specified by `facePtsArray` by the fact that connections between points of a cell have been ordered correctly (see my plot below)**

Here is some test data:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# An example of the array containing the mesh information: In this case the 
# dimensionality is (9,4,3) denoting 9 adjacent cells, each with 4 vertices and
# each vertex having (x,y,z) coordinates.
facePtsArray = np.asarray([[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
                          [1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
                          [1.0, 0.5, 0.0 ],
                          [0.0, 0.5, 0.0 ]],
                          [[0.0, 0.5, 0.0 ],
                          [1.0, 0.5, 0.0 ],
                          [1.0, 1.0, 0.0 ],
                          [0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ]],
                          [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ],
                          [1.0, 1.0, 0.0 ],
                          [1.0, 1.5, 0.0 ],
                          [0.0, 1.5, 0.0 ]],
                          [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ],
                          [2.0, -0.25, 0.0],
                          [2.0, 0.25, 0.0],
                          [1.0, 0.5, 0.0]],
                          [[1.0, 0.5, 0.0],
                          [2.0, 0.25, 0.0],
                          [2.0, 0.75, 0.0],
                          [1.0, 1.0, 0.0]],
                          [[1.0, 1.0, 0.0],
                          [2.0, 0.75, 0.0],
                          [2.0, 1.25, 0.0],
                          [1.0, 1.5, 0.0]],
                          [[2.0, -0.25, 0.0],
                           [2.5, -0.75, 0.0],
                           [2.5,  -0.25, 0.0 ],
                           [2.0, 0.25, 0.0]],
                          [[2.0, 0.25, 0.0],
                           [2.5, -0.25,0.0],
                           [2.5, 0.25, 0.0],
                           [2.0, 0.75, 0.0]],
                          [[2.0, 0.75, 0.0],
                           [2.5, 0.25, 0.0],
                           [2.5, 0.75, 0.0],
                           [2.0, 1.25, 0.0]]])



valueArray = np.random.rand(9) # Scalar field values for each cell

plt.figure()
for i in xrange(9):
    plt.plot(facePtsArray[i,:,0], facePtsArray[i,:,1], 'ko-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It would help if you turned this into a reproducible example by providing us with some fake data

Comment: @ali_m Please see my edit

Comment: Could you confirm what the dimensions of `facePtsArray` correspond to? It is `(6, 4, 3)`. I assume that the last dimension corresponds to the xyz coordinates, and since `valueArray` has length 6 then I assume that the first dimension corresponds to the number of vertices. Am I right in assuming that this is some sort a tetrahedral mesh, and therefore the 4 refers to the set of adjacent vertices in each tetrahedron?

Comment: @ali_m Yes you are absolutely correct - In this case there are 6 cells, each cell has 4 vertices (adjacent cells share two vertices) and each vertex has 3D coordinates assigned to it. I will update my question to reflect this.

Comment: If you're going to make an illustrative plot then 3D  would be more useful than 2D. Also, all your points are on a plane, so this example would be trivial to draw using `plot_trisurf`. Is your real data also like this?

Comment: @ali_m My real data is fully 3D but I think that I will confine myself to plotting 2D subspaces of the data. However, as you mention this  2D subspace ( surface) is not plane in general as in my example. Just out of curiosity, how would I use `plot_trisurf`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94038/discussion-between-ali-m-and-jack).